# Pack CollectionViewCells tightly together on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, uicollectionview

If you want to to pack the cells neatly together even if some of the other content in another cell is bigger, how do one do that?

If you look at the picture below, the first string is the biggest, but if I want to pack the other cells as neatly and tightly together as the first one, regardless of the size, how is this done?

I want to do this regardless of the size both from the sides and up and down.
I want the cells to be laid out as the arrows in this picture are pointing.

UPDATE: the first line of text is two cells packed togheter.

[image: ONE CELL WITH STRING PACKED NEATLY TOGETHER, AND THE OTHER ARE FAR AWAY FROM EACH OTHER, THIS IS BECAUSE THE FIRST STRING IS THE LONGEST]

Comment: Are you using a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`?  If not, what layout are you using?

Comment: I've tried using both collectionviewflowlayout and my own subclass of a collectionviewflowlayout, a custom layout.
But I just can't get it right, and my guess is that I have to subclass the flow layout, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you provide the code showing how you're achieving what you already have? It sounds like a relatively simple thing. Are you setting `itemSize` on the layout at all?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** to achieve this

Note: Below information's are taken from [**Raywenderlich blog**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)

You can subclass **UICollectionViewLayout** to create your own custom layouts , but Apple has graciously provided developers with a basic “flow-based” layout called **UICollectionViewLayout**. It lays elements out **one after another based on their size**, quite like a grid view. You can use this layout class out of the box, or subclass it to get some interesting behavior and visual effects.

You can see a good example in [**Raywenderlich blog**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)

**Example code:**

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *searchTerm = self.searches[indexPath.section]; FlickrPhoto *photo =
    self.searchResults[searchTerm][indexPath.row];

    CGSize retval = photo.thumbnail.size.width > 0 ? photo.thumbnail.size : CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    retval.height += 35; retval.width += 35; return retval;
}


- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 20, 50, 20); 
}
```

There are more delegate methods you can implement than this. Examples are given below

```
collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath
collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:
```

Comment: Not going to be that easy, from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH3-SW6, "The overall height or width of the line is then determined by the largest item in that dimension.". A standard flow layout isn't going to cut it, and you've not given much help on subclassing it to achieve the effect they're after.