# UICollectionViewCell Padding

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to set zero padding on collection view cells, I have set "Min Spacing" on the view controller to:

[image]

Yet it still has gaps between the cells:

[image]

Also I'd like it so that the cells wrap nicely depending on the width of the frame, for example each cell is 50px wide, so if there are six cells and I set the frame width to 150px, it will display two lines of three cells.

Yet if I set the frame width to 150 by doing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = self.collectionView.frame;
    frame.size.width = 150;
    self.collectionView.frame = frame;
}
```

It looks like in the above screen shot (too wide).

If I set it to something ridiculously small such as 10, it then wraps to some extent:

[image]

The UICollectionViewCell is set to 50 x 50:

[image]

I have also tried setting the size of the cell programatically, and also removed the UIEdgeInset:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

I have disabled auto layout just incase that had any interference. Any advice as to how I can remove the padding and also have them wrap depending on the frame width / height?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. I started an empty project with a single view, added a collection view as a subview, set the settings to the same as those shown above and made the frame in the storyboard to be 175x175. This spaces out the cells (which the flow layout does naturally). I change the frame size in viewDidLoad using your code, and it changes to 150 wide and the cells fill the gaps. There is something else going on that is not included in your question.

Comment: ah! You're using a UICollectionViewController. With this, you can't change the size of the collection view. It always fills the screen (unless you've embedded it in a container view controller). Let me see if the insets can be tweaked...

Comment: @jrturton Thanks for your time trying to reproduce this. I have just started afresh although the problem still remains. I have uploaded an example here which may be of use: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71160589/example.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a UICollectionViewController which, like a UITableViewController, has the collection view (or table view) as the base `view` property of the view controller. This means it can't be resized from within the view controller; it's size is controlled by its superview - either the window, in this case, which has it as the root view controller, or a parent view controller if you were embedding it.

If you want to reduce the collection view area so the cells abut one another, you can amend the section insets of the collection view in the storyboard. In your case, an inset of 15 left and right brings the cells together - this is 9 * 50 (450) plus 30 = 480 which is the width of a 3.5inch iPhone in landscape.

Obviously this will be different in the iPhone 5 or iPad. You can either calculate the insets at run time, use a collection view held in a standard UIViewController subclass, or hold the UICollectionViewController as an embedded view controller. The latter two will enable you just to specify a size, which is probably nicer than calculating insets.

Comment: Many thanks, I'm almost there, I've added a UICollectionView inside of a standard UIViewController subclass, however I still cannot resize the UICollectionView: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71160589/example2.zip

Comment: I'm not going to be able to look at that for a while, but you've either not connected the outlets, or you've left Autolayout on and are still setting the frame instead of editing the constraints.

Comment: I had the UICollectionView within a UIViewController - this wouldn't allow me to resize the UICollectionView. However, I added another view so that the hierarchy now looks like UIViewController -> UIView -> UICollectionView. I then resized the UIView, and it worked. Finally :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure those cells in the screenshot are 50x50 (EDIT: I guess they are...).

Check if you connected the UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource.

This it the method you need to implement

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize retval = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
    return retval;
}
```

If it does not work, try putting this code inside viewDidLoad

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
[flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(50.0f, 50.0f)];
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

Comment: It's a 4 inch retina screen in landscape; the size looks right to me. And your suggestions are just reimplementing in code what should already have been set from the nib.

Comment: Oh, yes. I did not notice that it is in landscape mode. The size does seem right. However, the collection view in his second screenshot does not have a width of 150 points. And about the suggested code, I'm quite aware it is just reimplementing what he thinks he has done in his storyboard file.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have re-implemented it using your code although the problem remains. I have uploaded a sample project displaying the bug here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/71160589/example.zip

Answer (score 3):

Implement this method in your ViewController

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 2; //the spacing between cells is 2 px here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the minimumInteritemSpacing is just that, a minimum value, so it can be larger if the UICollectionViewLayout class decides it needs to be

To correct for this you can create your own layout subclass, and implement the `- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, something like the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017257/how-do-you-determine-spacing-between-cells-in-uicollectionview-flowlayout) (see the second question, not the one marked as correct)

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* atts =
    [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.item == 0) // degenerate case 1, first item of section
        return atts;

    NSIndexPath* ipPrev =
    [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:indexPath.item-1 inSection:indexPath.section];

    CGRect fPrev = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:ipPrev].frame;
    CGFloat rightPrev = fPrev.origin.x + fPrev.size.width + 10;
    if (atts.frame.origin.x <= rightPrev) // degenerate case 2, first item of line
        return atts;

    CGRect f = atts.frame;
    f.origin.x = rightPrev;
    atts.frame = f;
    return atts;
}
```