# How to Subclass UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I would like to customize the `UICollectionView`, but all the tutorials on the web and in books use `UICollectionViewController` which I do not want to use.  I'm combining different kinds of `UICollectionViews` in the same `UIViewController`, so I don't want to limit myself by subclassing `UICollectionViewController`, which doesn't allow me to place several `UICollectionViews` in the same `viewController` along with other objects and labels.

How do I subclass `UICollectionView`?  Specifically, what kinds of methods need to be overwritten?  How do I layout what goes into it (i.e. where to put a text label, image, etc.)?  I'm familiar with the data source / delegate protocols, but not quite sure how to customize the cell's look, placement of sub items within the cell, what classes need to be overwritten/sub classed, etc.

A list of things I need to do would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you don't need to sub-class `UICollectionView` but you need to sub-class `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is the object which manages the display of the collection view items and it is highly customizable.

I suggest you follow [WWDC 2012:Advanced Collection Views and Building Custom Layouts](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_219__advanced_collection_views_and_building_custom_layouts.pdf)

The best tutorial which worked for me was by Apple called [Using the Flow Layout](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html).

Comment: Ok thanks. One follow-up question: If I customize UICollectionViewFlowLayout instead, who is responsible for ensuring that the embedded view can only scroll horizontally, etc.?  My custom UICollectionViewCell can handle layout & placement of the image within the cell, but someone still needs to ensure that every time this UICollectionView is added anywhere, it can *only* scroll left & right, etc.  NOTE: I can't let ViewController handle it because that lets other people add my custom layout and forget to restrict the scrolling.

Comment: `scrollDirection` is a property of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. So if you are subclassing flow layout, override `-setScrollDirection` to ignore the input and always set it to `UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526920/uicollectionview-with-dynamic-height-not-getting-same-space-between-cell)

Here are some good [Examples](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=uicollectionview) to customize your collectionview.

Use WaterfallCollectionView from this. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wont have to subclass a collection view. What you would need instead is subclassing UICollectionViewLayout to customize the positioning of cells within the collection view. And if you are looking for a customized look of a cell, you would also have to subclass UICollectionViewCell and assign the sub classed cells to the Collection View. 
The below links might help you,

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html

http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks Raj, but same question as above: If I customize only the layout/positioning and the content within each cell, how do I encapsulate other settings or restrictions for the entire UICollectionView?  Ex: if the custom collection view must be restricted to a certain scroll direction, certain background color, certain frame, etc. Not individual cell properties, and not layout properties (?) either, unless there is a way to set these in the custom layout?

Comment: The properties you mentioned (background color,scroll direction etc,.) are straight forward and directly accessible from the instance of UICollectionView. If you are only looking to set/get properties with no additional modifications over it, sub classing is just redundant. Nevertheless you can subclass UICollectionView and override the above properties setter methods, eg:
    -(void) setBackgroundColor:(UIColor*) backgroundColor{}