# Custom Collection View Cell Size

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to make `custom cell height`. But the next cell is starting from the `maxY` of previous cell. I want to fill the gap there. How to achieve that ?

This is what I am getting now : 
[image]

Here the 3rd cell is in the `vertically centered` to 4th cell, but it should be match the `minY` of 4th cell.

Here is how I am calculating size :

```
extension SomeController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let spacing: CGFloat = 10
        let smallestWidth = collectionView.bounds.width/3 - spacing

        if indexPath.item % 9 == 0 && indexPath.item != 0 {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: smallestWidth * 2)
        } else if indexPath.item % 4 == 0 && indexPath.item != 0 && indexPath.item % 8 != 0 {
            return CGSize(width: smallestWidth * 2, height: smallestWidth * 2)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: smallestWidth, height: smallestWidth )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482882/display-images-in-a-uicollectionview-how-to-achieve-fixed-vertical-spacing-bet) answer will help you.

Comment: @StrangeMan Thanks but their answer gives compile and run time errors.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [project](https://github.com/gsempe/UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout), especially UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout.m class