# UICollectionViewFlowLayout Subclass Not Working?

Tags: ios, subclass, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and I want to align all the cells to the left so that they are evenly spaced.

I have used Chris's solution from the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017257/how-do-you-determine-spacing-between-cells-in-uicollectionview-flowlayout), created a new subclass, copy and pasted the code into the .m file and then imported the subclass into the class which contains the CollectionView.

However, the cell's don't move. Have I missed a step to do with subclassing? Or is it something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you set the flow layout for the collection view in interface builder?

Assuming you created the collection view in interface builder, select it and go to the "attributes inspector" (it's the 4th icon along in the panel on the right side of the screen, go to it by tapping alt-cmd-4)

in the Collection View section at the top of the attributes inspector, select Layout -> "Custom" and you will see a text box where you can enter the name of your subclass (the default is "UICollectionViewLayout", replace that with your subclass's name).

if you created the collection view in code, you will need to do something like this:

```
UICollectionView *collectionView;
MyCollectionViewLayoutSubclass *myLayout = [MyCollectionViewLayoutSubclass new];
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = myLayout;
```