# UICollectionView cells not spacing at all

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, cellspacing

I have a collection view which is delegate and datasource of itself, and with a layout defined like this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{ 
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self){
        self.dataSource = self;
        self.delegate = self;
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 8, 0, 8);
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
        layout.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(1, 70);
        layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(60, 70);
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 4.0f;
        [self setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The code is run correctly except for the minimuminteritemspacing.

The result is a collectionview where the items in every section don't have any spacing at all.

The minimum spacing value I set should be adjusted upward, not downward, correct?

So why the result I see is like the one in this screen? (I colored every collectionitem so that is clear there is no spacing)

[image: CollectionView]

For further detail, here are the frames I'm logging, as you can see the third item starts exactly after the second one (145 pixels = 85(previousitem.x) + 60(previousitem.width)) with no spacing.

```
2014-04-22 10:25:49.954 App[15172:60b] self <PhotoIndexCollectionViewCell: 0x16576630; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (8 0; 60 70); layer = <CALayer: 0x165777a0>>

2014-04-22 10:25:49.955 App[15172:60b] self <PhotoIndexCollectionViewCell: 0x16578380; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (85 0; 60 70); layer = <CALayer: 0x16578520>>

2014-04-22 10:25:49.955 App[15172:60b] self <PhotoIndexCollectionViewCell: 0x16586620; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (145 0; 60 70); layer = <CALayer: 0x165866c0>>
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

I even tried adding this method which is actually called for every section, but the result is the same.

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return 4.0f;
}
```

Comment: please read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229350/cell-spacing-in-uicollectionview . i think it will help you.

Comment: I tried that, but still not working. I set up a minimum of 20 pixel to see if something will come up, but still the cells have no spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following `Delegate` methods to set spacing:

```
// Layout: Set cell size
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 //    NSLog(@"SETTING SIZE FOR ITEM AT INDEX %ld", (long)indexPath.row);
       CGSize mElementSize = CGSizeMake(150, 36);
       return mElementSize;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
       return 3.0;
}

 - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
      return 7.0;
  }

// Layout: Set Edges
 - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
   // return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
      return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);  // top, left, bottom, right
}
```

Comment: I have all these methods already implemented, with my values of course, and still no result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229350/cell-spacing-in-uicollectionview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017257/how-do-you-determine-spacing-between-cells-in-uicollectionview-flowlayout check this link

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, because in my case, the spacing was not working due to a mistake in the Interface Builder. So actually the correct way is of course with the delegate methods you're pointing at. Thanks

Comment: @Axy: What was the mistake? I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the apple documentation, the space may be adjusted *upward*  - But it looks that it may also be adjusted downward.
I honestly don't really understand why and don't have time to investigate this right now ( I'm facing the problem, and have to finish my work ;) ) - It may simply be a bug in the Apple layout, because it is presented to be so simple

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout/1617706-minimuminteritemspacing?changes=latest_minor

Anyway I see two ways to solve this :

1 - Compute the collection container bounds ( in the viewDidLayout function? ) by adding all items widths ( if width is not fixed ) or set it to ( itemWidth + minimumSpace ) * numberOfItems + minimumSpace ( for first padding )

2 - The radical way ( the one I have chosen ) : I embed my cell content in a view that is insetted by the amount I want. It just can't fail.

Cheers all

Comment: Something is not quite right. Can you tell me where the documentation states that the space between cells may be less than the one requested? It is a minimumInteritemSpacing so I expect it to be "not less than.. "

Comment: Yes. My bad... "This spacing is used to compute how many items can fit in a single line, but after the number of items is determined, the actual spacing may possibly be adjusted upward." - I'm wrong, it's not downward, but upward. However, I suspect there is a bug in the Apple Layout..

Comment: I've made some edits to my answer - I hope it is clearer. - One sure thing, the solution 2 is fast and works without headaches.