# Fixed item distance in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with a number of items which all have the same height and different widths. My problem is that the distance between each item only has a minimum value - I would like a fixed.
 What I have right now is something like:
[image: What I have]

What I would like to have is:
[image: What I want]

Thanks in advance!

#### Edit

My layout is as follows:

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
```

Comment: create custom layout and assign to collectionView  like  this   UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing =10.0f;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 50.0f;
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;

Comment: @Muhammad Adnan I have added my current layout to my question. The issue is still the same - that layout will work perfectly but it's still a minimum spacing, not a fixed.

Comment: Checks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017257/how-do-you-determine-spacing-between-cells-in-uicollectionview-flowlayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that UICollectionViewLayout does not support the case that I want, so I ended up using the [UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout pod](https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout) ([There also exists one for right alignment](https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewRightAlignedLayout)).